# Генерация трехмерных точек и нелинейная регрессия

Tags: python, pandas, машинное-обучение, matplotlib, scikit-learn

Требуется сгенерировать трехмерные точки, напоминающие трехмерное круглое сечение. При этом у этого сечения могут быть бугры и впадины, где бугры - это нормальное состояние, которое можно не учитывать, а впадины требуется определить.
Также возможно потребуется добавить шумы при малом количестве точек.
Основные вопроыс: с помощью каких библиотек я бы мог построить трехмерные точки, как правильно можно добавить шум для точек, и как строить регрессию так, чтобы можно было определить те самые "впадины"?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А "шум" у вас плоскостной (в сечении) или тоже трехмерный?

Comment: Но ведь все эти вопросы по отдельности не такие уж и сложные. Вы пытались что-то делать сами?

Comment: Рисунок действительно не очень корректен. На самом деле все точки должны быть трехмерными а не в сечении.

Answer (score 0):

Все эти вопросы не такие сложные, мне кажется вы можете во всём разобраться, если начнёте активно думать и гуглить. Но вкратце я вам дам наводку:

- с помощью каких библиотек я бы мог построить трехмерные точки

[Параметрическое уравнение окружности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%8B) - просто постройте круг как набор точек на окружности, используя функции `sin` и `cos`.

- как правильно можно добавить шум для точек

В `Python` есть библиотека `random`, но лучше использовать векторную версию `Numpy.random`. Просто добавьте с помощью этой библиотеки случайный шум по осям `X` и `Y` к полученным ранее точкам на окружности.

- и как строить регрессию так, чтобы можно было определить те самые "впадины"?

Мне кажется, вам нужно будет просто посчитать какой радиус окружности получается для каждой из точек и считать логистическую регрессию на основе значений этого радиуса.

Рисовать полученные точки можно средствами библиотеки `Matplotlib`.

Comment: Недостаточно ведь построить простой круг, необходимо, чтобы в нем также были недочеты.

Comment: @MarkTwain Второй пункт читали? Рандом можно применить и по-другому - например, выбрать с помощью рандома сколько будет недочётов, потом смоделировать недочёт как окружность опять же рандомного диаметра и добавить эту окружность в каком-то месте круга. Ну, то есть это творческая работа, все нужные инструменты у вас уже есть, нужно только их скомбинировать правильно.